# wrapper class for STL stream: forward operator<< calls

Tags: c++, stl, wrapper, operator-keyword

I'm currently writing a wrapper for STL stream to synchronize write calls from multiple threads. I have the following (simplified) code:

```
class Synchronize {
private:
    std::stringstream ss;
public:
    void write(std::string& str) {
        // locking ...
        ss << str;
        // unlocking ...
    };

    // other stuff ..
};

Synchronize& operator<<(Synchronize& o, std::string& str) {
    o.write(str);
    return o;
}

Synchronize& operator<<(Synchronize* o, std::string& str) {
    o->write(str);
    return *o;
}
```

Its now possible to call the `write()` method by using the `<<` operator on an object of the `Synchronize` class, but only by using a `std::string`. And `std::stringstream` also takes a lot of other stuff like `int`s and `float`s.

Is it possible to add this functionality to my `Synchronize` class without a ton of own `operator<<` functions? Would templates help? Or should I extend some class from the `iostream` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn your operator overload into a friend template

Inside your class write

```
template<typename T>
friend Synchronize& operator<<(Synchronize& o, T const& t);
```

Then the definition could be

```
template<typename T>
Synchronize& operator<<(Synchronize& o, T const& t) {
    o.write(t);
    return o;
}

 //edit
template<typename T>
void Synchronize::write(T& t)
{
    ss << t;
}
```

Comment: Accept the second parameter as `T const &`.

Comment: Additionally, if you want support for manipulators you will need to add a couple of extra overloads for `operator<<` that take the appropriate function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have many readers into a single destination. The architecture you created (a wrapper on std::stream with synchronized/locked writing) is not a good solution.

Here's code that doesn't work as you would expect:

```
Synchronize your_stream;

void thread_function1()
{
    output << "this is a message " << "from thread_function1\n";
}
void thread_function2()
{
    output << "this is a message " << "from thread_function2\n";
}
```

With your code, the output may be:

```
this is a message this is a message from thread_function2
from thread_function1
```

What you need is the ability to set synchronization points wherever/whenever you want:

```
your_stream  out;
out << synchronize_begin << "this is " << " a test" << synchronize_end;
```

(this buffers everything in a `synchronize_begin` object (which can be dumped into a stream) and when it receives a `synchronize_end` object, it locks a `mutex` (shared with other `synchronize_begin` instances) and writes to `out`).

or:

```
std::ostream  out; // any std::ostream type
out << synchronized << "this is " << " a test"; // synchronized ends here
```

(synchronized is a buffer instance that exits scope at the end of the line; when it is written into out, it locks, then writes it's data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this wasn't really about how to handle the synchronization. It was about the wrapper class for an STL stream and how to support more types than just `std::string` when using `operator<<` on my wrapper object.