# C++ wrapper class for iostream, use stream modifiers like std::endl with operator<<

Tags: c++, stl, wrapper, iostream

I'm currently writing a wrapper for an `std::stringstream` and i want to forward all the `operator<<` calls through my class to the `std::stringstream`. This works just fine now
(thanks to this question: [wrapper class for STL stream: forward operator<< calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752504/wrapper-class-for-stl-stream-forward-operator-calls)), but there is still one issue with it.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class StreamWrapper {
private:
    std::stringstream buffer;
public:
    template<typename T>
    void write(T &t);

    template<typename T>
    friend StreamWrapper& operator<<(StreamWrapper& o, T const& t);

    // other stuff ...
};


template<typename T>
StreamWrapper& operator<<(StreamWrapper& o, T const& t) {
    o.write(t);
    return o;
}

template<typename T>
void StreamWrapper::write(T& t) {
    // other stuff ...

    buffer << t;

    // other stuff ...
}
```

If I now do this:

```
StreamWrapper wrapper;
wrapper << "text" << 15 << "stuff";
```

This works just fine. But if I want to use the stream modifiers like `std::endl`, which is a function according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/endl, I simply doesn't compile.

```
StreamWrapper wrapper;
wrapper << "text" << 15 << "stuff" << std::endl;
```

Why? How can I forward the stream modifiers too?

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: There are overloads of `operator<<` that take a function, and then call that function on the stream: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662786/256138).

You'll want

```
typedef std::ostream& (*STRFUNC)(std::ostream&);

StreamWrapper& operator<<(STRFUNC func)  // as a member, othewise you need the additional StreamWrappe& argument first
{
  this->write(func);
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: @Mogria why the edit? The `STRFUNC` objects are function (pointers), so they can be called on the `ostream` directly.

Comment: because it needs to go through my write method, because of the other stuff in it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing a bit of extra work.  I normally use:

```
class StreamWrapper
{
    // ...
public:
    template <typename T>
    StreamWrapper& operator<<( T const& obj )
    {
        //  ...
    }
};
```

With a modern compiler, this *should* work for all concrete
types.  The problem is that manipulators are template functions,
so the compiler is unable to do template argument type
deduction.  The solution is to provide non-template overloads
for the types of the manipulators:

```
StreamWrapper& operator<<( std::ostream& (*pf)( std::ostream& ) )
{
    //  For manipulators...
}

StreamWrapper& operator<<( std::basic_ios<char>& (*pf)( std::basic_ios<char>& )
{
    //  For manipulators...
}
```

Type deduction will fail for the manipulators, but the compiler
will pick up these for function overload resolution.

(Note that you might need even more, for things like `std::setw(int)`.)

Comment: Does the perfect forwarding idiom alleviate the problem if you have r-value reference support?

Comment: @Tim I don't think so.  I don't see off hand how it would change anything.  According to Scott Meyer (who I definitely trust), template names can't be perfect-forwarded (and I don't see how you could implement it in a compiler), and the manipulators are all template names.

Comment: If he said that, then I trust it too. I only had in my memory his repeated statements that universal references "bind to everything".

Comment: @Tim They bind to everything in the sense that none of the lvalue-ness aspects enter into consideration.  They obviously don't bind to "everything" in the absolute sense; they can't bind to a totally unrelated type.  The problem here is that the compiler cannot deduce the type to determine whether it is reference compatible or not.

Comment: Yes, that's clear now. There is no way to deduce the template arguments without a specific overload to help the compiler.